# Get the actual HTTP request message that NSURLConnection generates?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to get the actual HTTP request message NSURLConnection generates? I've used "tcpdump" (Unix util) to figure it out, but was wondering if there is a way to get it programmatically?

For example, the URL string `http://www.example.com/somepath/resource?v=99` will apparently produce this if I use it in NSURLConnection:

```
GET /somepath/resource?v?99 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: {myprog}/1 CFNetwork/596.2.3 Darwin/12.2.0 (x86_64) (iMac11%2C1)
Accept: */*
Date: Wed, 19 Dec 2012 03:12:12 GMT+01:00
Accept-Language: sv-se
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: {long-string}
Connection: keep-alive
```

Some of these HTTP headers can be set to other values using `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` on the NSURLRequest (e.g. "Host" and "User-Agent") but some can't (like "Connection").

Answer (score 0):

[request allHTTPHeaderFields] sends an dictionary with keys and values only which yo have set ....

If you want to see the entire request , you can use the following tool...

http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2009/06/sniff-your-iphones-network-traffic/

I shows the request and response ...

Comment: Thanks, but since this is not an iPhone app, the link doesn't help. I can sniff the network traffic using "tcpdump" (Unix util), but was wondering if there was some way to programmatically get the actual request message that is sent. I think NSURLConnection is a bit obscure, but I'm not an advanced Cocoa programmer, so maybe it's just something to get used to.